# I want to run C# program without changing SQL Server instance or without changing SQL Server installed PC name

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows, sql-server-2008-r2

I have C# application which uses SQL Server R2 as its database. That database is on a separate PC by the name of `SERVER`. SQL Server's instance name also `server`.

My windows application uses `DataSet` to communicate with the database. Now my SQL installed PC name is change to another name, ex `SERVERHP`. Now all my coding works want to change my connection string. Are there any other easy way to do it ?

I am to tried to edit **hosts** file, but it does not work for me.

This is my coding style (http://goo.gl/FQrkp). I am using `DataSet` with `DataAdapter` with IDE designers.

I have 100 ~ 150 forms. Now I cannot compile all codings. I want to easy method to connect that SQL Server database.

I want to have a way to hide the change of the hostname of the computer

Comment: Tried to use IPs already?

Comment: the reason it, that method also want to compile all cording.I want know about they are any other method to do it in SQL SERVER SIDE ? like edit host file,using something like alias names

Comment: Do you have the source code to your C# application? This is precisely the reason many people put the connection string in their app.config, so that they don't have to mess with the source code when their database gets relocated.

Comment: Where do you have the connection string stored?

Comment: I must ask - what is "corde"?

Comment: http://goo.gl/FQrkp this is the my cording style.(sample from my cording)

Comment: Do you mean coding style? Code. not corde.

Comment: Any particular reason you didn't put the connection string in a .config file?

Comment: If you had a proper design, you would have the **connection string** in exactly **one place** and would need to adapt just this **one setting** ... so maybe you should take this need to change everything as a good opportunity to **fix your flawed design** and put the connection string where it belongs - in the config file, once and for all forms.

Comment: Visual Studio designer do for me evrything. When I add a Dataset then I add DataTableAdapter,then it will create connection string and apply it for DataTableAdapters.That's why i cannot manualy set connection string.it will store settings.sc file. So when it is want to be change now i have to change my all Modules.(All 120 Modules).That's why i am looking another method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of options:

1. Globally replace all server names with IP address in connection strings in the app
2. Globally replace all server names with the new server name in the app
3. Add a CNAME record to the DNS table on the server (assuming of course you're in the same network, which you are if you're using computer names)
4. Add an entry to the LMHOSTS file (you can add as many names as you'd like that point to the same IP)

Comment: I'll Try your 3,and 4 methods and replay you ,soon as possible.

Comment: @Elshan just out of curiosity, which solution did you end up using?

Answer (score 2):

As I understand, it is SqlConnection used to connect to database, or something like that. Why don't you use [SqlConnectionStringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)? Then you can dinamically construct connection string you need. Also, to get list of servers, you can use SqlDataSourceEnumerator, from namespace System.Data.Sql.

Comment: The thing is this program have very large amount of windows forms.so recompile is time wasting. i want to do it for this program only.newly cording are done by **SqlConnectionStringBuilder**.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to have a way to hide the change of the hostname of the computer (Server/Desktop/Virtualized instance of Windows, whatever) that is running your SQL Server.

This isn't my area of expertise, but I can't think of a way to do it that only involves your application code and just the computer.

If you control the local DNS you can create a CNAME entry with the old name that "points" at the new one. Depending on how your connection strings are stored, you might have to edit them or you might not. But you won't have to worry about the location of your SQL Server changing again because you can always edit your CNAME to point at the new location.

Note for the future - not your current problem: If you continue to use MS SQL Server in particular you'll want to be careful about moving it to a computer where it isn't the default instance because then you need to put the instance name in the connection string as well, which might force you to edit all of your application web.configs and app.configs again.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Visual Studio 2012 with your development efforts?  I ran into a conflict with the mini SQL db VS installs (Using Premium version) and had to modify the ConnectionStrings section of my Machine.config file to point to my SQL database.  For whatever reason, VS will write references to the mini db in the Machine.Config file (for whatever version of .Net you are leveraging) throwing potetial conflicts.

The file can be found in %systemroot%\Microsoft.Net\Framework64\dot net version\Config

If you're using an x86 processor the Framework64 folder is just called 'Framework'.